# How to mock dayjs timezone

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, dayjs

I have a function that translates a date in format `2021-06-07T07:28:55.69725+00:00` into string of hours and minutes in format `07:28`

```
export function getTime(dateTime: string) {
  return dayjs(dateTime).format("HH:mm");
}
```

Currently I'm locating in UTC+5, so the answer of this function to the argument `2021-06-07T07:28:55.69725+00:00` is `12:28`.
I want to test the work of the function but I need to mock timezone so that tests would be ok on machines in different timezones.
I tried next code but it still returns `12:28`.

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';
dayjs.extend(timezone)

describe('Function getTime', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    dayjs.tz.setDefault('Europe/Moscow');
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    dayjs.tz.setDefault();
  })

  it('should return time in format hh:mm', () => {
    const dateTime = '2021-06-07T07:28:55.69725+00:00';
    expect(getTime(dateTime)).toEqual('10:28');
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, that dayjs.tz.setDefault('Europe/Moscow') affects only dayjs.tz(). It means, that dayjs() will still show your local time.

You should change your function:

```
export function getTime(dateTime: string) {   
    return dayjs.tz(dateTime).format("HH:mm"); 
}
```

Now it should work as you expect.

Comment: I'm getting the same result (Expected: "10:28"; Received: "07:28") and it looks like you have to also `dayjs.extend(utc)` before.

Comment: For me it didn't work

Comment: Could you be more specific please? What didn't work?

Comment: @Maciej in this way, you make dayjs work for your local time (de), I assume Germany for example. Okay,  if you run tests locally, they will work. Now imagine your tests are run on some pipeline, azure for example, which uses utc time zone. then locally your tests will pass, if you provide hard coded value, but on pipileine will fail
that's why I suggested to use dayjs('some date') and it will work both on local and utc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73445727/is-there-a-way-to-run-dayjs-tests-on-desired-time-zone-locally/73719281#73719281 

I have an answer here