# Is there a way to run dayjs tests on desired time zone locally?

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, jestjs, dayjs

So here is the problem. I am migrating from moment to dayjs. There is a lot of code covered with tests, where dayjs is used. Some of them I would like to make run on specific time zone.

With moment I was using moment-timezone library.

> in some test data.test.ts
>
> ```
> import moment from 'moment-timezone';
> moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Berlin');
> ```

It would affect both moment and moment.tz and moment() will show Berlin time.

With the same approach, when we use

> `dayjs.tz.setDefault('Europe/Berlin')`

only dayjs.tz() is affected and changed to Berlin time zone, but dayjs() instance still keeps running on local time. I don't want to change the code to write with dayjs.tz(), I want to keep dayjs() logic and make tests run in timezone I specify.

Has anyone faced the same problem or knows how to solve it? I searched everywhere, but could not find a satisfying answer.

I can set process.env.TZ='SOME ZONE', but I don't want to affect the whole node enviroment.

Any clue will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

After looking everywhere, I came to conclusion, that in the tests I need to check not a static value, but dynamic dayjs generated value. Dayjs uses Date under the hood, Date uses system time.

> `expect(dayjs('some_date').format('YYYY-MM-DD')).toBe('something')`

This will work on local time, but for example in UTC time zone it will throw error.

What needs to be done, is just:

```
`expect(dayjs('some_date').format('YYYY-MM-DD')).toBe(expect(dayjs('some_date').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))`
```

So this way, we are checking dynamic dayjs value, which will use any time zone's time and will produce correct tests.

Comment: Can you explain how `expect(someCode).toEqual(someCode)` is not a meaningless no-op?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [here](https://day.js.org/docs/en/i18n/instance-locale) on how to change locales locally in dayjs.

Comment: In my case I need tests to run in my time zone. Locales won't help with this.